# Zend Studio 8 as Php Dev Tool

Tags: php, zend-studio

May i know how is Zend studio 8 for php development, i m beginner and how it it if i choose Zend Studio as php Dev Tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As linguistically challenging as your question is, I'm interpreting it to mean:

> I would like to know the suitability
>   of Zend Studio 8 for the purposes of
>   PHP development. I'm a beginner and
>   would like to know this information.
>   Thank you in advance.

I've used Zend Studio and Dreamweaver for PHP development, and I found Dreamweaver to be a better IDE. YMMV, however, I was designing websites *and* PHP backends at the same time.

If you are developing primarily PHP rather than XHTML *and* PHP then you might find Zend Studio better.

Comment: Thanks you very much for linguistic correction, basically i m in office and some times i m in hurry while writing. Any ways. I am designer (Graphics/web graphics/Flash/XHTML/CSS) and now wanna to learn Php as my friend suggested me to learn some dev skills. That is why i always like to take expert level suggestion while starting new things.. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Hello there. Zend Studio is a great tool, full integration with zend framework, zend server and has an embedded PHPUnit test runner. If you want, you can also buy Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP, which has an integrated copy of Zend Studio 8 within. Look for Adobe education store, they give up to 80% in discounts!